# Why CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess is necessary in ExecuteReader in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity Framework and do not understand why CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess is necessary for ExecuteReader. Below is my Code..

```
 using (var conn = new EntityConnection("name=EFRecipesEntities"))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Customers...");
       var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
       conn.Open();
       cmd.CommandText = @"select c.Name, C.Email from
       EFRecipesEntities.Customers as c";
       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
       {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              Console.WriteLine("{0}'s email is: {1}",
              reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
           }
       }
    }
```

Any help..

Comment: What happens if you don't use SequentialAccess? There is an ExceuteReader overload that does not take command behavior. If you are using EF why you drop down to ADO.NET instead of just use a linq query?

Comment: "could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly." This Exception occurs. I am just praticing EF, "Returning Objects from an Entity SQL Statement"

Comment: My advice would be just not to use Entity Sql. You can achieve almost everything you can with Entity Sql just using Linq to Entities. In practice you probably will never have to use Entity Sql. The exception you get is from EntitySql syntax analyzer. I don't exactly know what's wrong (maybe the capital C in `C.Email` while the entity is aliased as lower case 'c'?). I don't know either why changing the CommandBehavior would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2007/11/15/commandbehavior-sequentialaccess.aspx?Redirected=true

Well in an EntityDataReader sometimes a Cell (the intersection of a row and column) actually holds another Reader too. Caching nested Readers you have read past is kind of tricky. So at least for now we don't support non-sequential access.